# PHP get_file_contents & curl

Tags: php, curl

These two are the functions can capture remote address, for example this is a social network site *example.com/user?privacyemail.php*, this site is containing email of user or some kind of private info, curl and get content function in php can grap that, the problem is a have created a script with this, but it only captures javascript not the whole page, any suggestion? how to implement? this thing can be handy for patching security

Answer (score 1):

If authenticated properly, curl should retrieve the rendered page. Here's an example in PHP to retrieve a (rendered) page:

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "example.com/user?privacyemail.php",
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Some user Agent"
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: ok then fopen can help to write all rendered page into one file.. so that it will be accessible for later use